# LINQ C#: Exclude columns where total = 0, without knowing column names or type?

Tags: linq, sum, datacolumn

Using LINQ:

How can iterate over a table's columns without knowing the column names or type and exclude columns which equal zero?

Thanks!

Comment: For what purpose?  I suspect this field-level filtering (as opposed to record-level filtering) should be taking place in the UI instead of in the DAL...

Comment: No DB access, I'm getting a dataset passed in.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
 string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                             .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
                             .ToArray();

        List<string> cols = new List<string>();

        int n;
        foreach (string cn in columnNames)
        {

            if (dt.AsEnumerable().Where(s => int.TryParse(s[cn].ToString(), out n)).Sum(s => Convert.ToInt32(s[cn])) > 0)
            {
                cols.Add(cn);                
            }

        }
```

Comment: What if one record has 1 and one record has -1?

Comment: The nature of the data is that it will never be -1. But if you wanted negatives then just handle it in the boolean for </> 0

Comment: My point is do you want all columns that SUM to 0 or all columns that are ALL zeros?  If there are no negative then is shouldn't matter.

Comment: I'm excluding all columns that SUM to 0. And no, there are no negatives. Thanks for checking :)